# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in NSCoding of Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, swift

```
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!){
        aCoder.encodeObject(title.bridgeToObjectiveC(), forKey: "title")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.artist.bridgeToObjectiveC(), forKey: "artist")
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        NSLog("title: %@", aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as NSString); //<---|Causes crash here but still logs the title
        self.title = String.bridgeFromObjectiveC(aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as NSString)
    }
```

I have an NSObject conforming to NSCoding above but when it initializes and decodes calling `decodeObjectForKey` and halts the code with a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: Why are you using `NSLog` and not `println`? You should use `println` for your logging statements in Swift, there's no real reason to use `NSLog`.

Comment: @lxt sorry it was out of habit. replacing it in my code didn't resolve the issue though

Comment: @ixt there is indeed a reason to use `NSLog` instead of `println`, NSLog timestamps the messages.

Comment: Perhaps your key needs to be bridged to objective c as well? It's a shame we're stuck with no real swift frameworks, libraries or patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Double check you're inheriting from NSObject. Turns out you DO need a superclass if you want to do foundation-y things. That was my problem anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does already `class PlayerItem: NSObject, NSCoding{`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this without the bridge calls. It should still seamlessly bridge to NSString.

Comment: Yea it actually called an EXC BAD ACCESS again when I did this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this.

```
import Foundation

class AnyClass:NSObject, NSCoding{

    var title : String
    var artist : String

    init() {
        self.title = "TitleName"
        self.artist = "ArtistName"
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {        
        title = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as String
        artist = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("artist") as String

        println(title)
    }


    func encodeWithCoder(_aCoder: NSCoder!){
        _aCoder.encodeObject(self.title, forKey: "title")
        _aCoder.encodeObject(self.artist, forKey: "artist")

    }
}
```

Comment: Try as String instead of NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working sample that I built (as a command line utility) after reading the documentation located at the [Mac Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.pdf) or [iOS Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.pdf). Note: I converted this from Objective-C since that is what is in the PDFs that I linked to.

As Bill stated above, there should be no need to do bridging.

```
import Foundation

class Gloppo2 : NSObject, NSCoding {
    var Dorf2:String = ""
    var Druben2:String = ""

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.Dorf2, forKey: "Dorf2")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.Druben2, forKey: "Druben2")
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        Dorf2 = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("Dorf2") as NSString!
        Druben2 = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("Druben2") as NSString!
    }

    init() {

    }
}

var newGloppo = Gloppo2()
newGloppo.Dorf2 = "Sue"
newGloppo.Druben2 = "Perman"

NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(newGloppo, toFile: "gloppo2.bin")

var newGloppo2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile("gloppo2.bin") as Gloppo2

println(newGloppo2.Dorf2)
println(newGloppo2.Druben2)
```